# How to get rid of a sub-query in multiple join case with Slick?

Tags: postgresql, scala, join, slick

I am building somewhat less than trivial query using Slick. And in the process, I realized that Slick creates a join with a subquery instead of directly with a table.

Here is the code that builds the query:

```
val baseProgramSearchQuery = Programs.programs join
    Schools.schools on ((p, s) => p.schoolId === s.id && s.deletedAt.isEmpty) joinLeft
    Addresses.addresses on { case ((_, s), a) => s.addressId === a.id && a.deletedAt.isEmpty } joinLeft
    Medias.medias on { case (((_, s), _), m)  => s.mediaId === m.id && m.deletedAt.isEmpty }

  def search(searchCriteria: SearchCriteria,
             drop: Long = 0,
             take: Long = 100): Future[Seq[(Program, School, Option[Address], Option[Media])]] = {

    val q = for {
      (((program, school), address), schoolLogo) <- baseProgramSearchQuery
        .filter {

          case (((programs, schools), addresses), medias) =>

            List(
              searchCriteria.program.map(programCriteria => buildProgramFilters(programs, programCriteria)),
              searchCriteria.school.map(schoolCriteria => buildSchoolFilters(schools, schoolCriteria))
            ).collect({ case Some(criteria) => criteria }).reduceLeftOption(_ && _).getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])

        }
        .drop(drop)
        .take(take)
    } yield (program, school, address, schoolLogo)

    db.run(q.result)

  }

  private def buildProgramFilters(programs: Programs, programSearchCriteria: ProgramSearchCriteria): Rep[Boolean] =
    List(
      Some(programs.deletedAt.isEmpty),
      programSearchCriteria.name.map(n => programs.name.toLowerCase like s"%${n.toLowerCase}%"),
      programSearchCriteria.ready.map(r => programs.ready === r)
    ).collect({ case Some(criteria) => criteria }).reduceLeftOption(_ && _).getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])

  private def buildSchoolFilters(schools: Schools, schoolSearchCriteria: SchoolSearchCriteria): Rep[Boolean] =
    List(
      Some(schools.deletedAt.isEmpty),
      schoolSearchCriteria.name.map(n => schools.name.toLowerCase like s"%${n.toLowerCase}%"),
      schoolSearchCriteria.ready.map(r => schools.ready === r)
    ).collect({ case Some(criteria) => criteria }).reduceLeftOption(_ && _).getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
```

where `search` function is the one that gets called from one of the service classes.
The query that Slick generates is something like this:

```
SELECT
  x2.x3,
  x2.x4,
  x2.x5,
  x2.x6,
  x2.x7,
  x2.x8,
  x2.x9,
  x2.x10,
  x2.x11,
  x2.x12,
  x2.x13,
  x2.x14,
  x2.x15,
  x2.x16,
  x2.x17,
  x2.x18,
  x2.x19,
  x2.x20,
  x2.x21,
  x2.x22,
  x2.x23,
  x2.x24,
  x2.x25,
  x2.x26,
  x2.x27,
  x2.x28,
  x2.x29,
  x2.x30,
  x2.x31,
  x2.x32,
  x2.x33,
  x2.x34,
  x2.x35,
  x2.x36,
  x2.x37,
  x2.x38,
  x2.x39,
  x2.x40,
  x2.x41,
  x2.x42,
  x2.x43,
  x2.x44,
  x2.x45,
  x2.x46,
  x2.x47,
  x2.x48,
  x2.x49,
  x2.x50,
  x2.x51,
  x2.x52,
  x2.x53,
  x2.x54,
  x2.x55,
  x2.x56,
  x2.x57,
  x2.x58,
  x2.x59,
  x2.x60,
  x2.x61,
  x2.x62,
  x2.x63,
  x2.x64,
  x2.x65,
  x2.x66,
  x2.x67,
  x2.x68,
  x2.x69,
  x2.x70,
  x2.x71,
  x2.x72,
  x2.x73,
  x2.x74,
  x2.x75,
  x2.x76,
  x2.x77,
  (CASE WHEN (x78."id" IS NULL)
    THEN NULL
   ELSE 1 END),
  x78."id",
  x78."name",
  x78."file",
  x78."size",
  x78."tag",
  x78."createdat",
  x78."updatedat",
  x78."deletedat",
  x78."createdby",
  x78."updatedby"
FROM (SELECT
        x79."deletedat"                AS x42,
        x79."slug"                     AS x10,
        x79."updatedby"                AS x44,
        x79."tuitions_url"             AS x36,
        x79."acceptance_id"            AS x16,
        x79."description"              AS x7,
        x79."media_id"                 AS x11,
        x79."study_duration_unit"      AS x26,
        x79."min_pay_acceptance"       AS x34,
        x79."practicum_duration_unit"  AS x28,
        x79."internship_duration"      AS x23,
        x79."coop_duration_unit"       AS x27,
        x79."exam_cost"                AS x33,
        x79."class_size"               AS x17,
        x79."practicum_duration"       AS x22,
        x79."tuition_scheme_id"        AS x38,
        x79."id"                       AS x3,
        x79."terms"                    AS x8,
        x79."createdat"                AS x40,
        x79."short_info"               AS x15,
        x79."duration_unit"            AS x25,
        x79."coop_duration"            AS x21,
        x79."availability"             AS x39,
        x79."original_name"            AS x6,
        x79."origin_url"               AS x35,
        x79."credits"                  AS x19,
        x79."name"                     AS x5,
        x79."duration"                 AS x18,
        x79."schedule_id"              AS x13,
        x79."cources_url"              AS x37,
        x79."updatedat"                AS x41,
        x79."weekly_hours"             AS x24,
        x79."books"                    AS x32,
        x79."registration"             AS x30,
        x79."study_duration"           AS x20,
        x79."registration_intl"        AS x31,
        x79."internship_duration_unit" AS x29,
        x79."createdby"                AS x43,
        x79."study_kind_id"            AS x9,
        x79."school_id"                AS x4,
        x79."work_permit_attr_id"      AS x14,
        x79."ready"                    AS x12,
        x80."deletedat"                AS x60,
        x80."slug"                     AS x52,
        x80."updatedby"                AS x62,
        x80."website_url"              AS x50,
        x80."media_id"                 AS x51,
        x80."year_established"         AS x56,
        x80."about"                    AS x48,
        x80."classrooms"               AS x55,
        x80."display_copyright"        AS x57,
        x80."short_description"        AS x53,
        x80."dli_number"               AS x63,
        x80."id"                       AS x45,
        x80."createdat"                AS x58,
        x80."name"                     AS x47,
        x80."updatedat"                AS x59,
        x80."number_of_students"       AS x49,
        x80."address_id"               AS x46,
        x80."createdby"                AS x61,
        x80."ready"                    AS x54,
        (CASE WHEN (x81."id" IS NULL)
          THEN NULL
         ELSE 1 END)                   AS x64,
        x81."deletedat"                AS x75,
        x81."address2"                 AS x70,
        x81."zip"                      AS x72,
        x81."updatedby"                AS x77,
        x81."city"                     AS x71,
        x81."address1"                 AS x69,
        x81."continent_id"             AS x67,
        x81."id"                       AS x65,
        x81."createdat"                AS x73,
        x81."country_id"               AS x66,
        x81."state_id"                 AS x68,
        x81."updatedat"                AS x74,
        x81."createdby"                AS x76
      FROM "program" x79 INNER JOIN "school" x80 ON (x79."school_id" = x80."id") AND (x80."deletedat" IS NULL)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "address" x81 ON (x80."address_id" = x81."id") AND (x81."deletedat" IS NULL)) x2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
  "media" x78 ON (x2.x51 = x78."id") AND (x78."deletedat" IS NULL)
WHERE (((x2.x42 IS NULL) AND (lower(x2.x5) LIKE '%arts%')) AND (x2.x12 = TRUE)) AND
      (((x2.x60 IS NULL) AND (lower(x2.x47) LIKE '%alexander%')) AND (x2.x54 = TRUE))
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0
```

As you can see, first three tables are getting joined directly, but these are joined with `media' table is a subquery.
Why? How can I get rid of that?

Comment: this might be one of those moments where writing the SQL could me more convenient.

Comment: I can agree with it, however, in this particular question, it is more about learning

Comment: Please see this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897297/slick-join-with-subqueries) that is a much smaller and simpler example. The OP managed to fix it by carefully ensuring the join expression precede all filter operations.